# Are there any Python libraries/frameworks which generate AngularJS?

Tags: python, orm, angularjs, web-frameworks, web-frontend

I find the [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) architecture to be increasingly useful and relevant.

For example, it allows you to write once; deploy to:

- Website (for viewing in [web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browsers))
- Native mobile apps (using [Adobe PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) or similar)
- [Ubuntu apps](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/programming-languages/javascript/)
- [Windows Metro Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx) (for [Windows 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8))

Unfortunately this design has a major drawback; slower development time. Using any ORM and an associated form generator, one can develop their web application very quickly.

**Are there any ORM form generators for Python which can translate Models to AngularJS forms?**

[including CSRF token and RESTful setup; with JSON as format]

Answer (score 0):

There are not.  I had to look, but there's really nothing like that out there.  There are however quite a few articles about using AngularJS with Python.  Just Google "AngularJS python" and see what you come up with.  But you're going to have to do most of the work yourself!